# Typescript inference based on the expected function type parameters

Tags: typescript, function, parameters, call, inference

```
type DateFormat = {
  year: "numeric";
}

function calculateDate (dateFormat: DateFormat) {
  /**
   * 
   */
}

const format = {
  year: "numeric"
}



calculateDate(format)
```

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta&ssl=15&ssc=22&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsCAxA9gJwLYKgXigbwCgooQI40AuKAIgDsBXDCNASwGMaBuQgX0MIAzBnXbBWKOlHZwANuwayEEeIigAKACbLUmBNVXJ0WYAEoCxKAHoAVDctQbUBzat8B7SQGdgUQcew8IhIyCmp6JhYOGndCGXlFZUN1fz0zIA)

Currently in Typescript 4.2, the inferred type definition for `format` is:

```
{
    year: string;
}
```

This doesn't match the expected type alias, `DateFormat`, in the function call (`calculateDate`),  because the year property of type `string`, isn't as specific as the string literal `numeric`.

If however, I passed the `format` object argument directly from the function call, TS seems to be able to infer the type in the context of the call - and correctly validate the type against DateFormat.

```
calculateDate({
  year: "numeric"
})
```

Therefore, I'm wondering whether this is a limitation in Typescript inference-algorithm ability, or an active design decision of the language?

Answer (score 0):

you must use a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) `as const`:

```ts
const format = {
  year: "numeric"
} as const;
```

Quote from the docs:

> When we construct new literal expressions with const assertions, we
> can signal to the language that
>
> - no literal types in that expression should be widened (e.g. no going
>   from "hello" to string)
> - object literals get readonly properties array
> - literals become readonly tuples

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsCAxA9gJwLYKgXigbwCgooQI40AuKAIgDsBXDCNASwGMaBuQgX0MIAzBnXbBWKOlHZwANuwayEEeIigAKACbLUmBNVXJ0WYAEoCxKAHoAVDctQbUBzat8B7SQGdgUQcew8IhIyCmp6JhYOGj4oOC9pb2AeQhl5RWVDdX89MyA)

To answer the question in the comment:
Yes, it is a design decision, because there are use-cases for the wide and for the tight type.

An example where we want to have the wide type is this:

```
function foo(opts = {
  color: 'blue'
}) {}

foo({
  color: 'green'
})
```

In this case, we want the `color` property to be of type `string` - not `blue`.

[Playground example 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUcAOUDOiC8iA3gFCKIRwA2cATgFyIDkARlSAKZMkC%20AlMR4kSKdKXKUaDZgHNaHDmG78gA)

Comment: Sure, or:
`
const format: DateFormat = {
   year: "numeric"
}
`

This doesn't answer my question. I'm aware about the reason of why I can't call `calculateDate`. Im asking about whether this is design decision of the language, or a limitation.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm called [Excess Property Checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)

> Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error: